# Is Apple's PitchShift Audio Unit plugin using core animation?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, osx-lion, audiounit

Is Apple's PitchShift Audio Unit plugin using core animation to display the value bars for the parameter knobs in Mac OSX Lion?

I'm having this problem. [How to Host Apple's Pitch Shift Audio Unit plugin and the like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963223/how-to-host-apples-pitch-shift-audio-unit-plugin-and-the-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The answer is YES it is using core animation's CALayers.